# Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser found in modules xmlpull-1.1.3.1

Tags: android

I got this error when I add io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations to my project:

`Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser found in modules xmlpull-1.1.3.1 (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1) and xpp3-1.1.4c (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c) Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException found in modules xmlpull-1.1.3.1 (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1) and xpp3-1.1.4c (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c) Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory found in modules xmlpull-1.1.3.1 (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1) and xpp3-1.1.4c (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c) Duplicate class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer found in modules xmlpull-1.1.3.1 (xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1) and xpp3-1.1.4c (xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c)`

now i remove io.github.raamcosta.compose-destinations from my gradle and I still get error.